# Populating multiple attributes into XML using PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, xml, dom

I want to save my records from mysql table using PHP to an XML file.I am successfully retrieving records and saving into the database.
I want to populate my xml with ALL THE records in my customer table.(CustomerAccountNumber,CustomerAccountName ,AccountBalance, InvAddressLine1)

Here is my code:

```
<?
  $newAcct=$db_accnt;
$newAcctname=$db_accntname;
$newAcctbalance=$db_accntbalance;

$xmldoc=new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load('XML/customer.xml');
$newElement = $xmldoc->createElement('Row');
$newAttribute = $xmldoc->createAttribute('CustomerAccountNumber');
$newAttribute->value = $newAct;
$newElement->appendChild($newAttribute);
$root->appendChild($newElement);
?>
```

**My Question is :**

How can I generate customer.xml and how can i save thousand of records in efficient way so that based on the database in **THIS FORMAT** :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
  <Rows>
  <Row CustomerAccountNumber="CU002" CustomerAccountName="Customer 1" AccountBalance="289.00" />
  <Row CustomerAccountNumber="5U002" CustomerAccountName="Customer 2" AccountBalance="1899.00" />
   <Row CustomerAccountNumber="CU004" CustomerAccountName="Customer 3" AccountBalance="289.00" />
   <Row CustomerAccountNumber="5U032" CustomerAccountName="Customer 4" AccountBalance="1899.00" />
    </Rows>
```

I am not getting the clue what I need to do to generate multiple attributes for each record.Kindly help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XMLWriter

```
$xml =new XMLWriter();
$xml->openURI('file.xml');
$xml->setIndent(true);
$xml->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8', 'yes');
$xml->startElement('Rows');
while ( // fetch from DB ) {
  $xml->startElement('Row');
  $xml->writeattribute("CustomerAccountNumber", "1");
  $xml->writeattribute("CustomerAccountName", "2");
  $xml->writeattribute("AccountBalance", "3");
  $xml->endElement();
}
$xml->endElement();
$xml->flush();
```

Answer (score 2):

even if it's a XML, it's still a text file, you can just write it with `file_put_contents()`.

```
$xml='<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Rows>';

while($row=$result->mysqli_fetch_array()){
    $xml.='<Row CustomerAccountNumber="'.$row[0].'" CustomerAccountName="'.$row[1].'" AccountBalance="'.$row[2].'" />';
}
$xml.='</Rows>';
file_put_contents("customer.xml", $xml);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using SimpleXML, which will help you in you .xml generation. It will be as simple as :

```
$row->addAttribute("CustomerAccountName", "name");
```

Documentation here : http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php